# Class inheritance error in Model / ViewModel design

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, mvvm

I am tryint to 'port' my C# WPF app from non MVVM to MVVM, but I'm struggling with the inheritance of classes.

I have built some hierarchy in my model:

A bank contains a collection of patches and its IsSelected is bounded to the banks listview.

```
public abstract class Bank: ObservableCollectionEx<Patch>
{
    ...
    bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set { if (value != _isSelected) { _isSelected = value; OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsSelected")); } }
    }
    ...
```

And patch is defined below. The only interesting class (for this question) is ObservableObject.

```
public abstract class Patch : ObservableObject, IComparable<Patch>, INavigation, IParameter
{
...
```

ObservableCollection is defined as:

```
public class ObservableCollectionEx<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T : ObservableObject
{
```

ObservableObject is defined as:

```
public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
...
```

In my ViewModel I need a list of selected banks, so I have defined them:

```
public ObservableCollectionEx<Bank> Banks
{
    get ...
```

However this gives an error:

The type 'PcgTools.Synths.Common.Synth.Bank' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'ObservableCollectionEx'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'PcgTools.Synths.Common.Synth.Bank' to 'ObservableObject'.  G:\Data\Eigen\Informatica\KorgKronosTools\KorgKronosTools\ViewModels\PcgViewModel.cs    152 45  PcgTools

I (think) I need this construction because:

The IsSelected property of Bank is bound to a (banks) listview (which shows all banks). Multiple banks can be selected. So banks should support INotifyPropertyChange  (ObservableObject does this).

- The IsSelected property of Patch is bound to another listview (patch list view in the same window). Patches can also be (multiply selected).
- The first selected bank's patches are shown in the patch listview.
- When the first selected bank is changed I should refill the patches listview, so I need the Bank class to have ObservableCollection(Ex) supported.
- Patch only need to support INotifyPropertyChange (ObservableObject).
- I rather use ObservableObject instead of INotifyPropertyChanged because it gives some nice extra methods (for verification).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first question is why are you doing this? But if you really do need to, then it sounds as if the only requirement for your generic constraint is that the type implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
public class ObservableCollectionEx<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

You don't need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the `Bank` type as it's implemented by `ObservableCollection<T>`

You may be better of creating your own interface (which inherits from `INotifyPropertyChanged`) and has the methods that you need to access. Then use that custom interface as the constraint on your generic type, and implement it in `ObservableObject` and `ObservableCollectionEx`.

Comment: Yes I could do that, consequense is that I cannot use the derived functions inside the ObservableObject. I try to explain better in my question why I need this.

Comment: You mean that ObservableCollection already has INotifyPropertyChanged in itself? .... sorry stupid question (meaning I can find it myself) ... answer is Yes.

Comment: What methods of ObservableObject are required in the Bank type? You may be better of creating your own interface (which inherits from INotifyPropertyChanged) and has the methods that you need to access. Then use that custom interface as the constraint on your generic type, and implement it in ObservableObject and ObservableCollectionEx. Or test for its presence in ObservableCollectionEx (if (typeof(T) is IMyInterface) and remove the generic constraint to make it optional.

Comment: In that case ... I don't need it (as your first question says). I only am in doubt if I can accept the answer like this because I don't need it ... can you maybe rephrase the answer (for other people) and then I can accept it (hope this is an acceptable way of handling it).

Comment: I like your first alternative (implementing the methods in both, maybe calling a static utility class for it).

Comment: Thanks ... now I hope others may also learn from it ... and you helped me out a lot.